# Python: Validating Unknown File Schema Similar to XML

Tags: python, xml, validation, schema

I have software that outputs a configuration file with a unfamiliar file format I have not encountered before. The schema looks like very similar to an XML, except the "final" level in each tree does not have a closing tag - `< / >`. See the example below.

1. Is there a common file format that looks like this?
2. How would I validate the following on this schema if its not common using **Python**:

   1. the schema is valid (i.e. each attribute with children (`parent`) has a closing bracket) <> followed by </>
   2. all `<` are closed by `>`, etc

```xml
<Main Section>
    <Subsection>
        <Property 1> Value 1  # Note: this property does not have a closing tag
        <Property 2> Value 2
    </Subsection>
</Main Section>
<Section 2> Foo_Bar # Since the length of this "section" is only 1, this also does not have a closing tag.
```

Comment: You can use [`pyparsing`](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) to create a grammar. Your schema is somewhat similar to XML, but there is no one already existing (or at least well-known one that I'm aware of). There are a lot of other parsing libraries, supporting PEGs/CFGs/whatever you want, but pyparsing is really easy to understand and allows for quick and easy development, if your schema/grammar is relatively simple. Your reduced XML without attributes and with minor modification should be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: "Is there a common file format that looks like this?" Is the software a commercial one? does the sample show actual element names?

Comment: Looks like something produced by an intern on an off day, from a specification written on the back of an envelope by someone who thought that anything with angle brackets was close enough to XML to be useful to someone. Do you really want to be using software of such poor quality?